# Slick Social Share Buttons plug-ins with Responsive theme - number of tweets link problem

Tags: plugins, social-sharing

I've just installed latest version of Slick Social Share Buttons on top of Responsive theme.

In the settings page in Twitter Username I provided my twitter username.
The number of the times the link was hared shows fine in the widget, but if I click on the link, I'm taken to URL `https://twitter.com/search/realtime?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysiteurl.com`, which it not found.

I assume the proper url it needs to take me to should be something like
`https://twitter.com/search/realtime?q=MyTwitterUsername`

Am I missing something or its something wrong with plugins ?

[image]

**Clicking on number 1 takes me to page :**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine, because the functionality to share a website on Twitter should include the URL that you want your users to share. Keep in mind that the realtime Twitter-Searchfunction just shows recent results, not all of them, so the Link will never list all Tweets about your site.

The additional information section looks to me as if there was a possibility to show a 'Follow me on Twitter' button, which should include your username.

Comment: I thought clicking on the number should take the user to the twitter account page to see all tweets.

Comment: No, the number usually takes the user to the Searchpage for the Tweets mentioning this site.